# Algorithm for computing Pi that doesn't get harder the further you go?

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, pi

I'm looking for an algorithm for computing PI that doesn't get harder the more digits computed (e.g. using factorials). Additionally, digit computation must be feasible by giving a seed of a previous computation state which essentially allows "lazy" computation of some digits with the hope of not having to store the whole number in memory. Essentially the goal is to be able to request a "number range" of digits such as *provide digits 1450 through 1600* and be able to compute them at constant difficulty without having to provide all previous 1449 digits.

Computations in binary or hexadecimal are **acceptable**.

Comment: The very strong requirement that the computation *doesn't get harder at all* is provably impossible, but you can ask for the computational difficulty to increase very slowly.

Comment: Isn't it a bit early for such (Christmas?) wishes? There's only one known algorithm calculating digits without the earlier digits, but not in base $10$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula).

Comment: Compare `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe_formula` ... this is for binary (or base 16) digits, not decimal digits.

Comment: hexadecimal results are acceptable

Comment: @GEdgar Even this formula does not give the $n$ th binary digit with an effort not incresing with $n$ , although the effort increases rather slow.

Comment: The formula mentioned by GEdgar is the best we currently have. An astonishing formula, but what you are looking for is much stronger and in fact impossible. You cannot calculate the $10^{200}$ binary digit of $\pi$ "immediately". In base $10$ , the situation is even worse because such a formula is not known.